# How to read map of nested custom objects from Firestore in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a custom class (class has a constructor and setters/getters)

```
class Test() {
String field1;
String field2;
String field3;
}
```

and this is my Firestore snapshot
[image]

Fields "0" and "1" are my iterators, depending on how many elements have been created.
I'm using this line of code to determine how many times to read

```
for (int i = 0; i < documentSnapshot.getData().size(); i++)
```

I need to get all elements, make a new object Test for each of them `(o1{field1..3} .. oN{field1..3})` and store all objects in `ArrayList<Test>` but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get each field (0, 1, etc) from the ABCD document and create a `List<Test>`, first of all, please define your Test class like this:

```
class Test {
    String field2, field1, field3;

    public Test(String field1, String field2, String field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }
}
```

And right after that, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("collname").document("ABCD");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document != null) {
                List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<>();
                Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();
                data.values().forEach( h -> {
                            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) h;
                            testList.add(new Test(map.get("field1"), map.get("field2"), map.get("field3")));
                        }
                );
                Log.d(TAG, "size: " + testList.size());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "User doesn't exist.");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

According to your screenshot, the result in the logcat will be:

```
2
```

On the other hand, if you want to map an array of custom objects into a list of custom objects, then please see my answer from the following post:

- [How to retrieve data from nested array of maps in Firestore (Kotlin) for RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71193785/how-to-retrieve-data-from-nested-array-of-maps-in-firestore-kotlin-for-recycle)

Comment: Thx for reply. Question 1: .forEach requires API 24, mine is min 19. How to use this for lower APIs? Question 2: (Map<String, String>) h; this gets me warning about unchecked cast, how to get rid of it?

Comment: Q1. Perform a simple for loop over the list rather than calling `forEach()` method. Q2. I think that's an annotation for that. But don't worry, it won't break your code.

Answer (score 0):

To read a map of nested custom objects from Firestore in Android, you can follow these steps:

1. Define a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) class to represent your custom object.
   Create a reference to the Firestore collection or document containing the map of nested custom objects.
2. Call the get() method on the reference to retrieve the data as a Task.
   In the OnSuccessListener of the Task, extract the data from the DocumentSnapshot as a Map.
   Iterate over the Map and create instances of your POJO class from the data.
   Here's an example code snippet:

   ```
   FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
   DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("collectionName").document("documentName");
   docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>
   ```